# Custom Order in SQL for a columns particular data

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

I have a table for example as below:

```
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| Col1  | col2 | values1 | values2 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| item1 | A4   |       5 |      87 |
| item1 | A1   |       5 |      11 |
| item1 | A2   |       5 |      25 |
| item1 | A3   |       5 |      33 |
| item1 | A5   |       0 |      18 |
| item2 | A4   |      12 |      72 |
| item2 | A1   |       6 |      12 |
| item2 | A2   |       6 |      26 |
| item2 | A3   |       6 |      34 |
| item2 | A5   |       6 |      35 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
```

I wanted to order this above data on a specific condition, for eg: order the data of values2 in **ascending** where **col2=A5** *that means the data should be ordered as normal but where col2= 'A5'the row with the order of values2 should be ascending or descending should come first* 
It will look something like below.

```
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| Col1  | col2 | values1 | values2 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
| item1 | A1   |       5 |      11 |
| item1 | A2   |       5 |      25 |
| item1 | A3   |       5 |      33 |
| item1 | A4   |       5 |      87 |
| item2 | A5   |       6 |      35 |
| item2 | A1   |       6 |      12 |
| item2 | A2   |       6 |      26 |
| item2 | A3   |       6 |      34 |
| item2 | A4   |      12 |      72 |
| item1 | A5   |       0 |      18 |
+-------+------+---------+---------+
```

The data where col2='A5' should be ordered based on the values of column **values2**  in ascending or descending order. Can this be achieved?

To be specific, lets take only `col2` ordering. If I orderby `col2`. The rows will order by  **A1,A2,A3,A4,A5** without any dependency to col `values2` . My ask here is it when the order specifically A5 data of `col2`  the `A5` row with max values of column `values2` should come first followed by the lesser in descending,

Here we Suppose when I order by col2. we have two data with A5.

```
| item1 | A5   |       0 |      18 |
```

and

```
| item2 | A5   |       6 |      35 |
```

So the second value should come first because of the higher values of column `values2`.
Comes first doesn't mean it should be on the top, but I mean it should be after A4 but based on the values of `values2` for the col2=A5 the higher ones should come after A4.

** edited the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using an `ORDER BY` clause with a two level sort:

```
SELECT Col1, col2, values1, values2
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN col2 = 'A5' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    values2 DESC;
```

This would place all records for which `col2 = 'A5'` first, followed by all other records.  Within each of those 2 groups, the second condition sorts descending by `values2`.

Note: The OP has changed his question several times since I originally answered.  The original question asked how to order records with `col2 = 'A5'` first, followed by all other records.

Comment: just edited the requirement. The answer suits the old requirement, but the rest of the columns should be normally ordered and A5 values shouldn't come on the top.

Comment: would be unfair if I unselect this as  answer

Comment: Your new expected output makes no sense.  I suggest either reverting to your original question, or putting in more effort to explain what you actually want here.

Comment: The data where col2='A5' should be ordered based on the values of column values2 in ascending or descending order. Can this be achieved?

Comment: I still don't understand the sorting logic.  There is no order in your expected output which is obvious to me.

Comment: added explanantion.

Comment: It didn't help me to understand.  Maybe someone else can help you.